# CSS Modules aren't being loaded in any React Component

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, react-css-modules

I am attempting to utilize CSS Modules for styling my components, however they do not see to be applied.

I've created my React App using Create-React-App, which includes React(18.2.0) and ReactScripts(5.0.1). The WebPack configuration is the default generated by Create-React-App

```
Folder Structure Representation for Component:
/mypage
-- MyPage.js
-- MyPage.module.css
```

Simplified Component Minus unrelated logic:

```
import styles from "./MyPage.module.css";    

export const MyPage = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h2  className={styles.headerTest}>Pack Guide Page Test</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

MyPage.module.css contents:

```
.header-test {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Did you try with the class name as `headerTest` in `.css` file, I meant camelCase ? E.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/css-modules-so-y84lgs

Comment: I had! Unfortunately it didn't work either